# Adding search bar to the list without NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I have created a custom navigation bar in SwiftUI, now I am trying to add a search bar and make the `List` searchable without system built `NavigationView`. I was wondering is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: you can't use `.searchable` but you sure can implement your own search input field and filter results by the input. You might have a harder time to get the fancy "pull down to reveal search bar" behaviour though ;)